# how to build a query at run time by clicking on checkbox?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I needed to know how I can build a query by clicking on checkbox?
For example, I have 3 columns in each of the 3 columns I have a checkbox list that are dynamically generated, what I needed to do and the next
when the User click only 1 checkbox in column 1, the ajax does a search, if the User clicks on more than one checkbox in the same column, it does another search, for example

User clicked the checkbox only 1 column 1, ai creates the query:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $ id`

if they click more than one checkbox, do the following query:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $ id OR id = $ id`

and so on

would be a filter with several checkbox

can someone give me a hand?

thank you

```
$("#fam").find(".fcID").click(function () {
    $(':checked').each(function () {
        var valor = $(this).val();
        $.post("biblioteca/filtra.php", {
            valor: valor
        }, function (data) {
            $("#tabelafiltro").html(data);
            //if(data){ 
                //$("#tabelafiltro").html(data); 
            //} else{ 
                // alert("ERRO"); 
            //} 
            //alert(data); 
        });
    });
```

Comment: show us what you have so far.

Comment: It is calles "String concatenation". Just create the SQL as needed.

Comment: the select statement is a simple string. The idea is send whatever data is necessary over in the ajax call, iterate the data, if the data  has more than 1 object/array, then concatentate the string with `OR id = $id`. When you're done with the iterations, return the `OR's` and concatenate that with the beginning / end of the string

Comment: the problem is not the php, and I do not know how to pass several values ​​checkbox by ajax

Comment: then don't use ajax, submit form > process.

Comment: The issue is PHP only, not javascript/jquery/ajax.

Comment: I can not, it has to be via ajax, the results have to go is showing as marking the checkboxes

Comment: Use prepared/parameterized queries instead!  Do not manually build queries with just concatenation.

Comment: I can not click any button to submit the submit has to be done starting from checkboxes

Comment: Why was my edit removed? OP clearly states, `I do not know how to pass several values ​​checkbox by ajax` which is 100% what the code he provided was encompassing, Please respond @Praveen Kumar

Comment: Well, what @Ohgodwhy? I don't get your question. What's your edit anyways?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Dave Chen removed your edits. :)

Comment: Yup. Just noticed it was him, my sincere apologies....What the hell @Dave Chen!

Comment: Dude....You've murdered his question Dave Chen. You removed so much critical information. I'm rolling it back.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't notice there was another edit while I was editing!

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Why would you invent code and add it to someone else's question? If it is an answer, just post one.

Comment: @jereon I didn't ! He put the code in a comment so I put it in the question. The comment got altered and the code was lost. He didn't re-post it, so I put it in the question because it's 100% relevant.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy The comment seems to be gone, so that is what it looked like to me :-)

Comment: @jeroen: Yeah it was my fault, sorry about that!

Comment: Word brothers. Praveen's got this.

Answer (score 4):

Use this way.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="one" />
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="two" />
```

This way, when both are checked, your **POST** will have this:

```
option: one, two
```

Now, you can use PHP to query the MySQL in this way:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `id` IN ($ids);
```

This will translate into:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `id` IN ('one', 'two');
```

Comment: ok, but I do not know how to pass the values ​​of the checkboxes checked, and this issue, not php

Comment: Use AJAX this way: `$("form").serialize();`. Get it using `$_GET["option"]` or `$_POST["option"]`, if you use POST.